# Schedule a task to run two times a day between two date

Tags: sql-server-2016, jobs, sql-agent-job

I use SQL Server 2017. I need to schedule a job to run at 12am and 12pm for each days between 7th and 27th of each months. In the other word, i need to run my job two times per day between two date in each month.

Can i do that in one schedule task or I have to create a two jobs for each exact day?

12 am 7th month
[image]

12 pm 7th month
[image]

and so on and so on.

[image]

If i have to create a job for each hover of each day i will have several schedule.

**Update 1:** I did it by creating several steps in schedule tab but i am looking to do that in less steps.

[image]

**Update 2:**
If i can create two steps like below it will good for me.

1 : Occurs every month between 7th and 27th at 12 am

2 : Occurs every month between 7th and 27th at 12 pm

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to check if the date is in between 7th and 27th using `DATENAME` or `DATEPART`.

```
--IF (DATENAME(DAY, GETDATE()) >= 7 AND DATENAME(DAY, GETDATE()) <= 27) 
IF DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 7 AND 27
BEGIN
    EXEC [Your Stored Procedure]        
END
```

And then set the Daily frequency to start at 12:00 AM and Occurs every 12 hours.